# How can I tell whether screen is running?

Tags: python, linux, gnu-screen

I am trying to run a Python program to see if the screen program is running. If it is, then the program should not run the rest of the code.  This is what I have and it's not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
var1 = os.system ('screen -r > /root/screenlog/screen.log')
fd = open("/root/screenlog/screen.log")
content = fd.readline()

while content:
 if content == "There is no screen to be resumed.":
  os.system ('/etc/init.d/tunnel.sh')
  print "The tunnel is now active."
 else:
  print "The tunnel is running."
fd.close()
```

I know there are probably several things here that don't need to be and quite a few that I'm missing.  I will be running this program in cron.

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def screen_is_running():
    out = Popen("screen -list",shell=True,stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return not out.startswith("This room is empty")
```

Comment: Tried this as well and had no luck.

Comment: Could you post your error message? What version of Python you are using? Is it possible that screen is not installed where you run it?

Comment: Don't forget, the output of `screen -list` depends on the value of the NETHACK option. :) @spxxn: what is the output of `screen -list`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the error message that you redirect on the first os.system call is written on the standard error instead of the standard output. You should try replacing this line with:

```
var1 = os.system ('screen -r 2> /root/screenlog/screen.log')
```

Note the `2>` to redirect standard error to your file.

Comment: It is writing it to the file.  When I try to redirect it, it writes no info to the file.